# How to use overflow:hidden; text-overflow:ellipsis; inside a table with percentage widths

Tags: html, css

I would like to have a table that has a percentage width and each column will also have a percentage width. I want to use use css to do overflow:hidden; text-overflow:ellipsis; inside certain columns however it does not seem to be working for me.

Here is what I have:

```
<table style='width:50%;'>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td style='width:15%;'>column 1</td>
        <td style='width:15%;'>column 2</td>
        <td style='width:70%;'>column 3</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style='border:1px solid red;'>
                <div style='overflow:hidden; text-overflow:ellipsis; white-space:nowrap;'>this is some data 1</div>
            </td>
            <td style='border:1px solid red;'>
                <div style='overflow:hidden; text-overflow:ellipsis; white-space:nowrap;'>this is some data 1</div>
            </td>
            <td style='border:1px solid red;'>No hiding</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As the page gets smaller the third column  gets smaller instead of the first two columns show ellipsis and shrinking as I would expect.

[Here is a jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/wGznj/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
table {
    table-layout:fixed;
}
```

This might be what you are looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/wGznj/2/

More info on 'Table Width Algorithms' part, @ http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/tableformatting

> "With the fixed table layout algorithm, the widths of columns and of the table are not governed by the contents of the table’s cells."Instead, the width of each column is determined as follows:
>
> - Column objects whose width is not auto set the width for that column.
> - A cell in the first row, whose width is not auto, sets the width of the column it belongs to. If the cell spans more than one column, the width is divided over the columns.
> - Any remaining columns equally divide the remaining horizontal space, minus any borders or cell spacing."

Comment: I knew it would be something simple. Sad thing is that I learned about the table-layout attribute in the past and forgot all about it. Thank you.

Comment: @Mike Don't worry. I quite often forget of CSS properties I barely use as well :P